# Query GraphQL with multiple types

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to make a GraphQL query, out of the ordinary, but so far I haven't found anything related.

I would like to leave the where parameter with two optional types, see the example. Is this supported?

```
     input Person {
        name: String
        email: String
      }
    
      input Company {
        name: String
        domain: String
      }
    
      type GetSearch {
        name
        email
        domain
      }
    
      extend type Query {
        getSearch(where: Person | Company): [GetSearch]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Adding **Input Union type** to GraphQL was already proposed back in 2018, but it was never added. See [this discussion](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488) for more details.